# Efficient use of python generators in a tight double for loop over numpy arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, generator, cython

The speed bottleneck in my code is a tight double for loop over elements of two arrays, x, and y. A standard hpc trick to improve performance is to do the loop in chunks so that cache misses can be minimized. I am trying to use python generators to do the chunking, but the need to continually recreate the spent generator within the outer for loop is killing my runtime.

**Question:**

Is there a more intelligent algorithm for constructing the appropriate generator for performing chunked double-for loops?

**Concrete illustration:**

I'll create two dummy arrays, *x*, and *y*. I'll keep them short for illustration, but in practice these are numpy arrays with ~1e6 elements.

```
x = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'])
y = np.array(['e', 'f', 'f', 'g'])
```

The naive double for loop would just be:

```
for xletter in x:
    for yletter in y:
        # algebraic manipulations on x & y
```

Now let's use generators to do this loop in chunks:

```
chunk_size = 3
xchunk_gen = (x[i: i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(x), chunk_size))
for xchunk in xchunk_gen:
    ychunk_gen = (y[i: i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(y), chunk_size))
    for ychunk in ychunk_gen:
        for xletter in xchunk:
            for yletter in ychunk:
                # algebraic manipulations on x & y
```

Note that in order to implement a generator solution to this problem, I have to continually re-create *ychunk_gen* within the outer loop. Since *y* is a large array, this is killing my runtime (for ~1e6 elements, creating this generator takes ~20ms on my laptop).

Is there a way to be more clever about how I am constructing my generators that gets around this problem? Or will it be necessary to just abandon the generator solution altogether?

(Note: In practice, I am using cython to perform this tight loop, but all of the above applies regardless).

Comment: if `x` and `y` are lists in RAM then using generators like you do doesn't provide any benefit at all... also you could just run `counter = len(x) * len(y)`

Comment: Have you tried list comprehensions instead of generator expressions, and creating both chunk lists before the outer loop?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what you're actually doing inside your real loop and what your actual task is? Maybe we can provide better help if we see the big picture.

Comment: FWIW, in Python 2 you should be using `xrange()` not `range()` when creating large ranges. `range()` _has_ to build a list, even when you use it inside a generator expression;  `xrange()` doesn't, since it's effectively a generator itself.

Comment: List comprehensions will come with an additional memory allocation overhead that I need to avoid for performance reasons.

Comment: @JörnHees - see my comment to answer given by thefourtheye about RAM vs. cache. The chunked looping *does* provide benefit, and is a standard hpc trick used, e.g., in matrix multiplication.

Comment: Are you working with Python lists (as your code sample implies) or with one of the various array types available in Python? Python lists are (essentially) arrays of _pointers_ to data objects, so doing chunking with them may not provide the benefits you require. For actual arrays you could use the arrays provided by the `array` module, but I suspect you'll get more speed from `numpy` arrays.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - sorry for the confusion, I'm not just counting the number of elements. What I am doing is computing pairwise distances, and updating a histogram. I just didn't want to sidetrack the problem.

Comment: @PM2Ring - yes, in practice I am using contiguous numpy arrays for exactly this reason.

Comment: @aph Yeah I asked because I knew you're not just counting :-). Pairwise distances doesn't sound very non-standard, so maybe there's a way to have numpy actually do the work for you (on the whole arrays or on chunks) so you don't have to loop yourself at all or at least less. That could very much improve the speed. But again, we'd need to really know what you're actually doing.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring - I edited my post (again) to point out that I"m using numpy arrays.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - if there is a pairwise numpy routine, that would solve *all* my problems. I have looked specifically for this and come up blank, but that does not mean there is not a lesser-known method available.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - on second thought, I would be surprised if there were a numpy built-in for exactly what I need. I  mis-spoke earlier: I am actually computing pairwise distances in a periodic box, which is not very standard.

Comment: @aph Well I'm guessing you're breaking it down to simple calculations anyway, so maybe there's an equivalent numpy-ish breakdown. Or something in scipy, or this numexpr that Xavier just mentioned could help, or something else. But it's hard/impossible to help with your problem X if you solely ask about a detail of your solution Y. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676) if you haven't heard of it before.

Comment: I'm btw not saying your question is bad, it's actually well-done and interesting on its own, and answers to it can help you. I just mean that you might be even better off asking about your actual problem directly.

Comment: Roger that @StefanPochmann - I have spent quite a lot of time optimizing many different aspects of the general periodic-pair-counting problem, and just didn't want to bog down a question about a specific bottleneck with a long rigamarole. But I understand your point, thanks for gentle nudge about good question-asking practices.

Comment: What is coded in `cython`?  The 'algebraic manipulation' code, or all of this generator business?

Comment: Everything besides the initial array creation, @hpaulj - I almost always use cython whenever I have nested loops in a speed bottleneck.

Comment: Can't you simulate a chunked generator directly with C style iteration?

Comment: Yes, sure, I know how to solve this problem the old-fashioned way in straight C. I was asking about generators because this seemed like something there would be existing elegant syntax for, e.g. with itertools. That does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Does `itertools.tee` help?

Comment: @hpaulj - I just fiddled around with .tee for this. It can be jiggered for this purpose, but comes with significant memory overhead. Since cache misses are the root of the problem, this hurts. Your original suggestion to dispense with the fanciness and just use straight C syntax seems to be the fastest solution by a significant margin. It ain't pretty, but that's C for you.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the creation of your generator expression is killing your running time because it is not optimized by cython.

A better solution, which keep care of all cache optimization things is to use [numexpr](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/). As the manipulation of x and y are algebric  it should fits your constraints very well (numexpr can do a little more)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the `ychunk_gen` all over again within the xchunk-loop.  Maybe the following will be faster:

```
chunk_size = 3
xchunk_gen = (x[i: i+chunk_size] for i in xrange(0, len(x), chunk_size))

def ychunk_gen(some_dependency_on_outer_loop):
    # use some_dependency_on_outer_loop
    for i in xrange(0, len(y), chunk_size):
        yield y[i: i+chunk_size]

for xchunk in xchunk_gen:
    for ychunk in ychunk_gen(chunk_or_something_else):
        for xletter in xchunk:
            for yletter in ychunk:
                # algebraic manipulations on x & y
```

But perhaps there is an even better way:

I assume `x` and `y` are `numpy` arrays, so you can reshape the arrays and then loop through every line:

```
for xchunk in x.reshape((len(x)//chunk_size, chunk_size)):
    for ychunk in y.reshape((len(y)//chunk_size, chunk_size)):
        # the letter loops
```

In http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html I read that if you wanted the data not to be copied by `reshape`, you should change the `shape`-property of the data:

```
x.shape = len(x)//chunk_size, chunk_size 
y.shape = len(y)//chunk_size, chunk_size
```

Comment: Does this second numpy solution work if chunk_size does not divide the array lengths? It looks like it doesn't, since reshape has hard requirements on array length preservation, but maybe there's something I don't understand?

Comment: You are right with the shape restrictions, but i think thats easy to work around?

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.tee` may give a modest time savings:

```
y = np.arange(100)
def foo1(y):
   # create ygen each loop
   # py3 so range is a generator
   for j in range(100):
       ygen=(y[i:i+10] for i in range(0,1000,10))
       r = [x.sum() for x in ygen]
   return r

def foo3(y):
   # use tee to replicate the gen
   ygen=(y[i:i+10] for i in range(0,1000,10))
   ygens=itertools.tee(ygen,100)
   for g in ygens:
       r=[x.sum() for x in g]
   return r

In [1123]: timeit foo3(y)
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
In [1125]: timeit foo1(y)
10 loops, best of 3: 144 ms per loop
```

But based on

http://docs.cython.org/0.15/src/userguide/limitations.html#generators-and-generator-expressions

> Since Cython 0.13, some generator expressions are supported when they can be transformed into inlined loops in combination with builtins, e.g. sum(x*2 for x in seq). As of 0.14, the supported builtins are list(), set(), dict(), sum(), any(), all(), sorted().

I wonder what `cython` is doing with your chunked generator expressions.

---

Reshaping and iterating on rows doesn't help much with time.

```
def foo4(y):
   y2d=y.reshape(100,10)
   for _ in range(100):
       r=[x.sum() for x in y2d]
   return r
```

is a bit slower than the `teed` generator.  Of course relative timings like this could change with array size.